# Slow performance of TFS with maven

Tags: java, performance, maven, tfs, junit

We are use TFS 2010 for building java maven project (Team Price build extension). We have issue with performance when runing JUnit tests under TFS via Maven it takes more than 4 hours. When we execute tests from console on build agent machine it takes 17 minutes.

How we can improve performance of tests execution under TFS?

Comment: If the slowness is caused by a get taking a long time, it could be to do with [this](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2010/11/slow-connection-when-connecting-to-team.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of problem was writing maven console log to file by TFS. I minimized amount of log information. Now performance is OK.

Comment: Thanks for this Alex - I'll take a look at how we're writing to the log file in the Team Build Extensions and see if we can do something like introduce some extra buffering to speed that part up.  What was the size of log before and you reduced it?  (That should help me reproduce the problems you were seeing)

Comment: The size of console log was about 20 MB, now size of log 9 mb.